# How to filter members by xprofile field via BuddyPress REST API

Tags: buddypress

Documentation states that result of querying list of members could be limited by xprofile field of string type:

https://developer.buddypress.org/bp-rest-api/reference/members/#arguments

But what is the string format? I cannot find information anywhere. Does it work at all?

Comment: I'd guess it's the same as BP_User_Query xprofile_query, if that's easier to find.

Comment: Php implementation is relatively easy to find, but the question is how this maps to HTTP GET parameters? 
BP_XProfile_Query: https://github.com/buddypress/BuddyPress-build/blob/aceb7e9dbeaebd24f5bc513889b4e54c95731968/bp-xprofile/classes/class-bp-xprofile-query.php

Answer (score 0):

xprofile parameter is not working, see https://github.com/buddypress/BP-REST/issues/425. Hopefully it will be fixed soon.